# Element.scrollIntoView() method animation speed too slow in Chrome

Tags: javascript, performance, animation, scroll, js-scrollintoview

Is there any way to adjust `Element.scrollIntoView()` scrolling speed with defined transition animation as `behavior: "smooth"`. Somehow, scrolling is too slow in Chrome, but fine in Firefox.

Comment: No, not with the standard method.

Comment: @Kaiido does the same apply to `window.scrollTo()`. I mean, do they implement the same algos for animation?

Comment: Yes they do indeed.

Comment: I'm building an app at the moment and have the same problem. It's fine in iOS also. Non-native scroll libraries are unfortunately so janky.

Answer (score 2):

The same thing happened to me and my problem came from the fact that I was calling `Element.scrollIntoView()` from within a "scroll" event-handler.
The thing is `scrollIntoView()` does trigger the scroll Event and so calling it within a *scroll* event handler creates an (almost) infinite loop.

Comment: What's the best way to solve this problem? (when you need to call scrollIntoView() from "scroll" event-handler)

Comment: What would be the point of scrollIntoView that's not on a scroll event? Just having some random content scrolling in on page load? Surely most people would have this on a scroll event, no?